# Python: List argument passing

Tags: python, list

I understand we pass reference of an object during argument passing in Python.

So,

```
def changer(b):
    b[0] = "spam"

l = [1,2]
changer(l)             # l is now ["spam",2]
```

However, if I do,

```
changer(l[:])          # l remains [1,2]
```

What is passed to the function in the second case when I pass list slice?

Comment: You will pass a copy of `l` in the second example.

Comment: Note that this behavior isn't exclusive to function calls. You can see the same thing happen if you do `l = [1,2]; b = l[:]; b[0] = "spam"; print(l); print(b)`

Answer (score 1):

`l[:]` creates a copy. See slicing. The copy is passed into the function and the function modifies the copy of l. Therefore, l will remain the same.

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested
>   elements. This means that the following slice returns a new (shallow)
>   copy of the list.

Comment: I'd change "splicing" to "slicing." When you splice a list, you usually edit it in-place, removing the spliced section. When you slice a list, you leave the original list untouched. This is also consistent with the `slice` built-in.

Comment: Good point...Thanks.